# How do I turn off the Comment Pager for a Type?

Tags: 7, comments, paging

I have a Type configured as below, asking for 50 comments per page. However, I'm getting the pager on nodes that have as little as a single comment.

[image]

I've looked at responses [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40062/comment-pagers-in-d7-they-appear-even-when-the-page-has-only-1-comment). However, those responses point to a configuration in another view. I have no other views on this node type. It uses Responsive Bartik with no other modifications.

Outside of setting an extremely large "Comments per page" and using CSS to hide the pager, how else should I attack this?

Comment: have you found a solution to your question?

Comment: Sadly no. Some other issues and answers refer to a conflict in another block or view, but this is a pretty vanilla page. Currently, we allow an high number of comments and CSS hide the pager. :(

Comment: it's been quite a while.... but, can you tell what module/custom code that you're using to allow for customization settings for "Post Date Format" and everything below it (as your screenshot indicates)? It seems like that can be something that is causing pager issues...